# Spreadsheet Formula (math)

Tags: excel

This is purely a math question!

I simply can't get my head around this formula. It is so simple, but I can't get it to work in general.

I have 2 columns of numbers.

- Columns A+B is the full number of apples (100%).
- Column A: is the number of apples that I have eaten.
- Column B: is the number of apples that are    left.

I need column C to be the percentage of apples that are left out of the full number.

For example.

```
 A   B   C
 0   3   100%
 5   0   0%
 2   2   50%
```

Can anybody wrap their heads around this?

Comment: Not a programming question. Should have been asked at Super User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total = A + B

Left out apples = B

Percentage of left out apples = (B / Total) * 100

Consequently, here's the formula:
**Column C = ((Column B) / (Column A + Column B) * 100)**

Here's what you should type-in in Excel:

```
=(B1/(A1+B1))*100
```

Comment: I'd remove the `*100` and just format the cell as a percentage.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm (after removing *100 and formatting as percent)

Answer (score 0):

A = No. of apples eaten, B = No. of apples left . A+B = total no of apples. So Total no. of apples left out of the full amount are (A+B)-A/100.